# How to assess the risk of touching a live wire

Tags: circuit-protection, electricity

I know that a macbook charger works at 16.5 V and supplies 60 watts of DC through the laptop. There is a small area (in front of the AC to DC converter) where the insulation appears to be torn off exposing live wire with a small tear of about half a millimetre, where the wire is about a few millimeters in diameter. The charger has been supplying power at a reasonably quick rate for quite a while now.

I have 2 questions, one is when plugged into the mains, will this be able to do serious damage or kill me if I brush or hold this part of the wire? Second is, wouldn't it be more dangerous to touch it when it is not plugged in to the laptop, since the voltage is reduced?

Comment: http://www.darwinawards.com/darwin/

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Is it the DC wire or the AC wire which is exposed? Exposed mains wiring (other than protective earth ground) is a safety hazard that is unacceptable by today's standards. I would replace the wire. If it is DC wire, I would not be as concerned. Electrical tape from a reputable vendor might be a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your first question: It COULD kill you if something else is wrong too, so let's assume that just in case.  But most likely you won't get more than a nasty shock and that's IF the adapter has gotten wet or somehow else conducts from the exposed wire to your hand.

The real danger here is not that the charger alone could zap you, but that it can be live at mains voltage relative to ground/earth.  If you get in contact with that wire, your hand will also become live at main voltage relative to ground.  (Depending on which way the adapter is plugged in, the exposed wire could be the neutral which usually is safe unless there's something terribly wrong.  But the rule is to always assume the worst, i.e. that it's the live wire.)

What makes it dangerous is that your other hand or your foot or something, may be connected to something grounded.  Now you've got one hand at live and another at ground, current will start flowing through your heart and you could die.

There should be a [GFI/RCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) that breaks the current (fast enough to save your life) when it returns through earth instead of neutral, but it might malfunction or not be sensitive enough, or may be limited to wet areas like bathrooms. Or you might be touching another lethal adapter which has exposed the other live/neutral wire and not conduct through earth at all.

---

Answer to your second question: Laptop or no laptop won't matter.  Connecting the laptop to the power brick is not going to reduce the input voltage.

The laptop does not act as a voltage divider at all.  And even if it would, the live wire would still be at mains voltage.

The adapter is galvanically isolated.  What happens on the high voltage side stays in the high voltage side, and what happens on the low voltage side stays on the low voltage side.  It transfers power through a transformer, and believe it or not, that power is not electrical but magnetic.

---

Credit to Solar Mike for pointing a few things out.

- Electrical insulation tape is not a safe fix as it doesn't seal against water well enough.
- GFCIs/RCDs might not be required for the outlet the adapter is connected to.

Comment: I know, but it could kill you.  I should probably add a few more "could"s in my answer, but I'm afraid it won't be scary enough.

Comment: could you clarify "If you get in contact with that wire, your hand will also become live at main voltage relative to ground?" Are you describing what could happen if the voltage converter malfunctions?

Comment: @HarrySvensson so many factors are involved as you should know : it's not necessarily the voltage but the timing during he heart cycle, but i will delete it,

Comment: @mechanic... Not malfunctions.  I mean if you touch the exposed wire, or if there is something that forms a conductive path between the exposed part of the wire and your hand e.g. lots of water or poking at that wire with a conductive stick.

Comment: Gfci / rcd  / elcb are not always protecting all circuits - regulations vary between countries : UK has elcb protecting the whole installation , other EU countries just use elcb for "wet" areas such as power in bathroom....

Comment: but i mean i thought the voltage converter changes it to low dc voltage. Also, with respect to your answer to the second question, my assumption was that the laptop essentially acts as a voltage divider.

Comment: @mechanic...: Check my last two edits.

Comment: i'm probably testing your patience here but surely 'What happens on the high voltage side stays in the high voltage side' means that you can't be exposed to the mains voltage in any case? (considering the exposed part is on the other side of the adapter). Anyway, it's not that i'm trying to prove this is safe, but it's just very confusing that sources i've read state 'current, not voltage kills you' yet the current is solely dependent on voltage and your resistance to ground. Am i oversimplifying things?

Comment: It's actually not the just current that kills, but it's a high enough current for a long enough time.  And your resistance varies and apparently current is a more reliable metric than voltage for determining danger.

Comment: If the exposed wire is on the output side of the adapter, electric shock is not a danger.  But it can however short to the other wire and create a fire.

Comment: Another nitpick: Touching Neutral can kill you, never assume neutral is "safe to touch". All it needs is a bit of faulty wire and an appliance with a large current draw.

Comment: @TurboJ i think i see what you're talking about. But one more question, suppose there is no appliance connected and i touch a neutral wire. Surely then earthing has no purpose? For example, a charger is not connected to the laptop, then my fingers could complete the circuit

Answer (score 2):

A picture would help, but with supply side damage it is best to replace that cable - easily available.

Just covering with insulation tape could be dangerous if it gets wet - spilt drinks etc.

Comment: you see i had it covered with insulation tape for a month or so but i just took it off because it started to go brown

Comment: @mechanic...: Sounds like it got heated?  Disconnect the adapter and check if the exposed wire itself is (really) hot, that could hint at some really bad issue.

Comment: @mechanic... are you talking about the dc cable ie the output - because if so, any of the shield strands which touch the inner cable can cause heating (and sparks ...) best to replace the power supply then (unless you are up for cracking open the device - which isn't that easy...)